# React functional component, how to access outer function variable from element dragStart/dragEnd callback

Tags: javascript, react-functional-component

I am facing an issue with below code in react functional component

In dragStart and dragEnd, I am not able to access **color** which is at component level.

```js
const Card = (props) => {
  let color = props.color;

  function click() {
      // below line is perfect
      console.log(color); // red/green/blue
  }
  function dragStart(ev) {
    // Below lines gives error; //color is not defined
    console.log(color);
  };
  
  function dragEnd(ev) {
    // Below lines gives error; //color is not defined
    console.log(color);
  };

  return <div className="card">
      <div 
        draggable={true}
        onDragStart={dragStart}
        onDragEnd={dragEnd}
      >
        card
      </div>
      <div
        className="card-body"
        onClick={click}
      >
      Card body
      </div>
    </div>;
}

export default Card;
```

What mistake I am doing. I am new to react hooks.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you using this component? Can you show the code where you are rendering this component? For the color prop to be defined you have to pass it down. Since you mentioned 'hooks' in your question, maybe you want to use color as state not prop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-surf-v873v?file=/src/components/Card.js, and the error I see so far is that you are missing the reducer prop in the flop container:

```
     <div className="flop">
        {flopped.map((card) => (
          <div
            className="cardContainer"
            key={JSON.stringify({ suit: card.suit, number: card.number })}
          >
            <Card
              key={JSON.stringify({ suit: card.suit, number: card.number })}
              suit={card.suit}
              number={card.number}
              stack={true}
              turned={card.turned}
              locked={card.locked}
              last={card.last}
              reducer={context.dispatchStock} // <== add this
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

See https://codesandbox.io/s/great-wescoff-hy83s

Let me know if there's any other issue

EDIT
I also found that you're using this.setState inside a functional component. Do this instead:

```
    ...
    const [localState, setLocalState] = useState({
        rotation: props.turned ? 0 : -180
    });
    ...
```

```
    ...
    const slideBackAnimation = (time) => {
        let rotation = null;
        if (lastTime !== null) {
            const delta = (time - lastTime) * 0.4;
            rotation = Math.min(0, localState.rotation + delta);
            setLocalState({ rotation });
        }
        lastTime = time;
        if (rotation !== 0) requestAnimationFrame(slideBackAnimation);
    };
    ...
```

Comment: Oh sorry silly mistake. Did not thought about it.

Could you tell if I am doing it right by passing the slices and dispatchers as props.

Comment: I think you can actually access the reducer directly with useContext inside the Card component.